# Hide and show views on UIMapKit annotation click

Tags: swift, swift5, mapkitannotation

I want to show a storyboard View whenever a user taps on an annotation and it's subtitle is visible. My code works somewhat but isn't doing exactly what I want. Here's my code

```
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var homeMapView: MKMapView!
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

@IBOutlet weak var viewToShow:UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupMapPin()
    viewToShow.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 450)
}



func setupMapPin() {
    
    homeMapView.delegate = self
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  9.0833, longitude: 7.5361)
    homeMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    annotation.title = "Title"
    annotation.subtitle = "Randome subtitle"
    
    let defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: annotation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 2000, longitudinalMeters: 2000)
    
    homeMapView.setRegion(defaultRegion, animated: true)
    
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
  

    
    if boatview.transform == .identity {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.boatview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 450)
       }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration:1) {
            self.boatview.transform = .identity
        }

    }
    
   
}

 }
```

`
I want the view to animate in when the user **clicks the annotation and the subtitle is visible** i.e when the annotation is active. The view animates in when the annotation is clicked and active but doesn't animate out when it's inactive. What am I not doing right here?